# Redirecting all subfolder URLs to another domain

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I have a domain that is `example.com/portfolio/some-url`.

I would simply like to direct all traffic that would normally go to the subfolder `/portfolio` to a new domain:

```
new-domain.com/
```

How would I do this? Htaccess? Is there a way to do it to separate affiliation?

Basically, all the `/portfolio` items are affiliate links that I don't need anymore and don't want the possibility of it decreasing my site rank in Google. What type of redirect should I use?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `RedirectMatch` for this with 301 code. This will tell Search Engines resource has moved permanently.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/portfolio/(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/portfolio/$1
```

Answer (score 6):

Just write in the `/portfolio` subdirectory `.htaccess` file, and will moved all your subdirectory to newdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/porfolio/$1 [R=301,L]
```